# HttpError: <HttpError 502 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json returned "Bad Gateway">

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

We're seeing is issues with our test and production application starting approximately 6:30PM PST 4/30/2013, and requests are failing with the following error.

```
HttpError: <HttpError 502 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json returned "Bad Gateway">
```

The API console seems to be having issues as well, the Drive API url below only loads up partially.

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/
```

Comment: All fixed now, there was a temporary outage, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Ali - confirmed that the problem is fixed on our end.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the error was due to a [temporary outage](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&ts=1367564399000&iid=64e8939482b9bd9acb72fd621760fad7).

I would like to add that, for future issues like this (5XX errors), it might be useful/informative to keep an eye on [Google's Apps Status Dashboard](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status&ts=1367564399000).